# JavaScript find substr in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate an input field to see if the value entered contains a number or the letters X or Y at the start of the string:

```
var t_index_array = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'X', 'Y'];

for(var i=0, l=t_index_array.length; i < l; i++){
   if (document.form.topography_index.value.toUpperCase().substr(0,1) != t_index_array[i]){
    alert ( "The Topography index field needs to start with a number between 0 and 9 or the letters X or Y." );
    valid = false;
    return valid;
   }
}
```

This isn't working as the value of t_index_array[i] is always 0.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use regex?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: See answers provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current logic is checking if it starts with *every* character, not one of the characters (which is of course impossible).

Instead, you mean something like:

```
var t_index_array = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'X', 'Y'];

if(!t_index_array.some(function(val) {
    return document.form.topography_index.value.toUpperCase().substr(0,1) == val
})) {
    alert("The Topography index field needs to start with a number between 0 and 9 or the letters X or Y.");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

But I would use a regex, which is even simpler.

```
if(!/^[0-9xy]/i.test(document.form.topography_index.value)) {
    alert("The Topography index field needs to start with a number between 0 and 9 or the letters X or Y.");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

EDIT: Explanation of `/^[0-9xy]/i`.

- `^` match at beginning of input.
- `[0-9xy]` a character 0 through 9, or x, or y
- `i` case-insenstive

Comment: Thx the regex looks like the way to go, but I don't understand the i.test bit...should this be if(!/^[0-9xy](document.form.topography_index.value.toUpperCase().substr(0,1))

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex for this case...

```
var patt1 = /^[\dXY]/i;
var result =inputfield.match(patt1);
//the result will hold the expected output
```

if result is null..then its not starting with digits or x or y

Thank you @RobG

Comment: He only wants to test the *beginning*.

Comment: I think you mean `/^[\dXY]/i` and the OP can drop the `.toUpperCase()` part. And *test* is more appropriate. And the OP probably wants `inputfield.value`. And with *match*, the result won't be empty if no matches are found, it will be `null`.